# Obtain public IP from which RDS instance will connect to an external master?

Tags: amazon-rds

To configure RDS MySQL as a slave to an external master (for minimal downtime migrations, as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.NonRDSRepl.html)) I need to determine which IP the instance will connect from (to allow traffic from it to my external master).

How can I determine the IP address if the instance isn't publicly accessible?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out there's no way to do external master replication with an RDS instance that doesn't have the `publicly accessible` option enabled--no outbound traffic will be allowed outside the VPC.

Further, there's no way to modify an instance's `publicly accessible` setting--a new instance must be launched (e.g., from a snapshot).

Comment: This does seem to be the case, but thankfully you can just modify your rds configuration to be 'publicly available'. You do not need to recreate your instance.

Answer (score 0):

well create a test replication user at the external master that can connect from '%' and use that one as user at the RDS instance
once connected , you will see the iP in the processlist and then you will be able to restrict the access to only that IP, dropping the '%' test replication user